# How to apply a perl filter to code loaded with require

Tags: perl, filter

I have been able to setup a filter using [`Filter::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/Filter::Simple), however for it to work I must add the line:

```
use myfilter;
```

in every Perl file I want to filter.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use myfilter;

print "Loading...";  # this line is filtered

require 'bar.pl';    # code inside the bar.pl file IS NOT FILTERED

print "Done";        # this line is filtered

1;
```

====

Questions:

1. Is it possible to apply a `Filter::Simple` filter to all the Perl code, including all the files loaded with `require`?
2. Is it possible to make an alias to perl in such a way that the filter will be applied to every piece of code?

Answer (score -1):

How about calling perl with the `-Mmyfilter` option?

You could `mv /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/perl-real` and then create a wrapper script `/usr/bin/perl` like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/perl-real -Mmyfilter $*
```

Then, all your scripts should include the module.